# bootstrap4: how to flow a large text into multi columns like MSword

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In bootstrap4 how to have a MSWORD type multicolumn text flowing

eg in word we have:

[image]

In bootstrap4 the below code will craete a two column grid

eg:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    ...... some text
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    ...... text
  </div>
</div>
```

but here manually i have to split the text into two columns

How can this be down more automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need Bootstrap for this, native CSS is enough!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.newspaper {
  column-count: 3;
}

h2 {
  column-span: all;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="newspaper">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is `column-span: all;` also needed

Comment: If you skip this, the title also wrapped to multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you need Bootstrap, instead CSS can handle this.

CSS Class:

```css
.two-column-text {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="two-column">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
</div>
```

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.two-column-text {
  column-count: 2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="two-column-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)